# Sound card with 8 line-in

Tags: sound, hardware, soundcard

What soud card with 8 line-in can you recommend for ubuntu? It can be an internal one or usb/firewire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on your price range, but the [M-Audio Delta 1010](http://www.m-audio.com/products/en_us/Delta1010.html) is popular. For a bit more money (and more inputs) the [RME](http://www.rme-audio.de/) cards are supposed to be good.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is possible to use 2 or more Delta 1010 cards in a single workstation?

Comment: I don't know about that. I know Jack can only use a single interface at a time. I think this is because it's hard to keep multiple cards in sync. I think I've read of multiple RME cards being used, but they may have ways to synchronise their sample clocks. This also suggests there is a way to make them look like a single interface.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the Focusrite Saffire Pro 40 FireWire card. And yes you can use multiple soundcards, with FireWire you can daisy-chain them. With PCI cards like the M-Audio Delta 1010 you can add as much cards as you have slots available and you should be able to use multiple cards at once.
USB is not an option, at the moment there are basically no supported USB2 soundcards with that much IO.

Best,

Jeremy